# Proving $(Qv) \cdot (Qw) = v \cdot w$ given $Q$ is orthogonal

Tags: orthogonality

there is a proof for $Q$ being a $3x3$ real matrix, and $v,w \ in \mathbb{R}^3$ that shows $(Qv) \cdot (Qw) = v \cdot w$.
It goes like this:
$(Qv) \cdot (Qw) = v \cdot (Q^{T}Qw) = v \cdot (Iw) = v \cdot w$.
I don't see how the first first equality goes to the next, as in, how does the $Q$ from the front of $v$ go into the bracket with $Qw$?

Comment: You are using $(Qv)^T=v^T Q^T$; transposition of matrices is multiplication-reversing.

Comment: Thanks, should''ve realised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot product of two vectors $v$ and $w$ is given by $v\cdot w = v^T w$. Therefore,
$$(Qv)\cdot (Qw) = (Qv)^T(Qw) = v^TQ^TQw = v^Tw = v\cdot w$$

Comment: Ah right thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) pp 325-326 details this more. I don't affiliate Kuldeep Singh.

[image]